Will buiding and running on NixOS be supported?
I want to build and run Tezos node and baker on a NixOS server. I'm able to build what seems to be a functional Octez node and baker using nix-build, but the default.nix file warns that it's not supported. Are there plans to support Nix builds? Am I taking a risk in running a mainnet node built this way?
I'm currently building octez-v20.1 on a NixOS 24.05 server. The octez-node seems to work fine, but octez-node --version reports that it is "unknown (not-available) (Octez 0.0+dev)".

There is already a “best effort support” for hacking Octez using Nix (as demonstrated by the various nix file, like shell.nix, flake.nix, etc.).
Several Tezos core engineers are keeping them up to date, so I’d say you probably can give it a shot.

Are there plans to support Nix builds?
I don't think there is a plan currently, except I didn't hear of it.
Am I taking a risk in running a mainnet node built this way?
Yes, you are.
